# Why can't I conditionally add to a list this way?

Tags: c#, operators

I'm pretty sure Java lets you do this, I might be wrong though.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
bool istrue = false;
myList.Add(istrue ? "something" : void);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can't use `void` like that. It's not an expression, it's a keyword used in method sigs. And the `?:` operator requires all operands to be expressions. And I'm even surer that you can't do this in Java.

Why not an if statement? It makes it so much clearer what you're trying to do, precisely because `void` is meaningless in that context.

1. Only add something if `istrue`, do nothing otherwise:

   ```
   List<string> myList = new List<string>();
   bool istrue = false;

   if (istrue)
   {
       myList.Add("something");
   }
   ```

   In one line:

   ```
   if (istrue) myList.Add("something");
   ```
2. Add something if `istrue`, but add a null value otherwise:

   ```
   List<string> myList = new List<string>();
   bool istrue = false;

   if (istrue)
   {
       myList.Add("something");
   }
   else
   { 
       myList.Add(null);
   }
   ```

   In one line (`null` works with the `?:` operator):

   ```
   myList.Add(istrue ? "something" : null);
   ```

Comment: Not elegant.  I'd be ok with: myList.Add("something") if isTrue;

Comment: +1 for if statement: if(istrue) myList.Add("something"); // Clear and concise

Comment: @Matthew: You can always drop the braces and put everything on one line if you want, as Mark shows.

Answer (score 7):

How about this

```
public static void AddIf<T>(this List<T> list, bool flag, T obj)
{
    if (flag) { list.Add(obj); }
}
```

just pass in flag and item

```
myList.AddIf(true, item);
myList.AddIf(item!=item2, item2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`void` is only legal (1) as a return type of a method, or (2) as the underlying type of a pointer type. (thanks @Eric Lippert).

This code will not even compile.

Comment: In order to fix this, use null instead of void.

Comment: That wouldn't be the same behavior. The question isn't to add a string or null, it was to add or not add with an expression inside the call to Add.

Comment: @Kyle, that would actually add the value null.  I want an "abort" option.

Comment: Inside that ternary you will not be able to abort. This would require two lines.

Comment: @Kyle I know.  This is more of a discussion question than a "how to".

Comment: void is too a type. It is a type that is only legal (1) as a return type of a method, or (2) as the underlying type of a pointer type. Because of that, it's a pretty lousy type, I must say. But it is a type.  Whether it is a type or not is irrelevant; in order to be used in a conditional expression it has to be an *expression that is valid as an operand*, and a type is not an expression valid as an operand of anything except "typeof".

Comment: Huh, there actually is a type `System.Void` and you can do `typeof(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad this doesn't work. If I invoke .Add I expect something to be added. What if this type of logic was in a method you couldn't see?

```
myList.Add( aBlackBox.Method() );
```

Did it add or didn't it?!

Comment: I don't understand, aBlackBox.Method() has a return type, doesn't it?  You'd know if something were added based on that.

Comment: Unless the method called looked like "return istrue ? "something" : void"

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that Java *won't* let you do that. The `void` keyword means that a method returns nothing. It's not the same as `null`, nor is it the same as an empty list, nor can you use it to mean "do nothing", which is what you seem to mean here.

Comment: You might be right, it's been a while since I've used Java.  Nevertheless, I wish there were a way to "abort" expressions.

Answer (score 0):

void isn't the same as NULL,

try

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
bool istrue = false;
myList.Add(istrue ? "something" : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add(false ? "true" : "false");
```

Will add "false" to the list.

I'm guessing your code above is having a problem adding void as string.

Try

```
myList.Add(istrue ? "something" : string.empty);
```

**EDIT** 
If you're trying to only add when something is true then just do

```
if(isTrue)
   myList.Add("something");
```

Comment: My goal is to actually not add something if isTrue evaluates as false.  I wish void were an expression, basically.

Comment: null would add the value null to the list.  I want an "abort".  Doesn't exist in c# though (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you're trying to conditionally add elements as part of the object initializer instead of adding piecemeal in subsequent Adds. I was in the same boat.

This is the top Google result, so for posterity...

As long as the conditional is the same for every element in the collection:

```
var myList = (from s in new List<string> { "alpha", string.Empty, "gamma" }
              where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)
              select s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your extension method:

```
public static void Add<T>(this IList<T> source, T item, Func<bool> predicate)
{
    if (predicate())
    {
        source.Add(item);
    }
}
```

And you use it this way:

```
myList.Add("something", () => somethingElse != null);
```